# How can I use a basic_string<unsigned char> via swig in python?

Tags: swig

I have a function defined like this:

```
int foo(basic_string<unsigned char>& output);
```

swig could "translate" this without any problems to a c++ wrapper for python.
When I call foo from a python script, I always get the following error:

```
TypeError: in method 'foo', argument 1 of type 'std::basic_string< unsigned char,std::char_traits< unsigned char >,std::allocator< unsigned char > > &'
```

How do I need to define the parameter, that it fits a basic_string reference?

Answer (score 1):

I needed a typemap in the swig interface file:

```
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) std::basic_string<unsigned char>(std::basic_string<unsigned char> tmp)
{
    $1 = &tmp;
}

%typemap(argout) std::basic_string<unsigned char>&
{
    if ((!$result) || ($result == Py_None))
    {
        $result = PyDict_New();
    }
    PyObject *outValue;
    outValue = PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize((const char*)$1->data(), $1->length());

    PyDict_SetItemString($result, "$1_name", outValue);
}
```

After that added, my function returned the basic_string instead of having it as parameter in python.